# MPI transport for zeromq sockets

Tags: c++, mpi, amqp, zeromq

i read on the web

"ØMQ is much higher-level than MPI, at least in theory you can implement MPI transport for ØMQ sockets"

I wanted to to see if any one else has tried to implement this

I also wanted to see if any one could offer some advice or consulting on implementing this before i blindly start

thanks

Comment: What would be the benefit of such an implementation?  The commonly used MPI libraries can already work over TCP sockets.  You could argue that 0MQ's programming model is easier (being somewhat higher level and having fewer features), but you'd be replacing it with MPI's anyway.

Comment: I doubt that anyone did that - MPI is mainly used in tightly coupled High Performance Computing applications while Message Queuing is suitable for loosely coupled and more general distributed systems.

Comment: The quoted statement is seems backwards to me, anyway.   I would think that if A is much higher level than B, it would be *hard* to implement B on top of A, and *easier* to implement A on top of B, rather than vice-versa, right?

Comment: @JonathanDursi, I read that as "in theory one can use MPI to transport 0MQ messages", i.e. 0MQ presents abstraction on higher level than MPI.

Comment: so it wouldn't make much sense? I'm just looking for something opensource in which I can contribute i.e I sort of know mpi very well..

Answer (score 0):

I dispute the notion that 0MQ is higher-level than MPI.  MPI supports a wide range of features not found in low-level communication libraries, including collectives and datatypes.  Does 0MQ support all of the collective operations found in MPI-3?  Does it have a way to describe application communication topologies using distributed graph notation?  Does it support arbitrary user-defined datatypes?

Note that I am not saying that MPI is higher-level than 0MQ, because 0MQ appears to make some things a lot easier than MPI does.

I like the ideas of 0MQ and in many respects the design is better (the stateless nature solves a lot of problems with multithreading), but I don't think it is prudent for anyone to say that one is higher or lower level than the other.